# Как правильно оформить следующее предложение: "Стеснялся спросить, играет ли он..."?

Tags: пунктуация

> Но он стеснялся спросить(,) есть ли у него какие-либо письма.

Или же:

> Но ты стесняешься спросить(,) играет ли он в карты.

Какой знак нужно поставить перед стеснялся спросить? Как это вообще оформить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да просто запятую поставить, это же обычное СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.

Двоеточие можно поставить лишь при очень большом желании, да и то при определенных условиях - например, если вопрос не один, а сразу несколько.

*Но ты стесняешься спросить: играет ли он в карты? есть ли у него какие-либо письма? что он здесь вообще делает?* и т.п.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно почитать о том, каким образом регламентируется отсутствие заглавный букв в начале каждого вопросительного предложения в приведенном Вами примере? Периодически сталкиваюсь с тем, что иногда в таких случаях перечисляемые предложения пишут с заглавной буквы (кроме первого, разумеется), а иногда - со строчной. Очень хотелось бы узнать, на основании какого правила необходимо принимать такое решение.

Comment: Точно и не скажу... Посмотрите в справочниках Розенталя, я там вроде бы видел.

Comment: Спасибо! Надо будет поискать.